# i have some difficulties with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

Hi im getting a error when going localhost:3000/login
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/login' => 'user_controller#login'

  get '/register' => 'user_controller#register'



  get 'static_pages/home'

  get 'static_pages/store'

  get 'static_pages/about'

  get 'static_pages/search'

  root 'static_pages#home'

end
```

Controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def login
    end
    def register
    end
end
```

Comment: And when you look in your Heroku log, what do you see? Posting error messages generally helps your case when you're asking for help.

Comment: if i remeber right i didnt use heroku for this project

Comment: That message looks like a Heroku message... I see now that you're trying to connect to localhost. That said, including log output is a pretty helpful practice.

Answer (score 1):

In routes.rb when you indicate controller-action pair for specific route you should not write `user_controller` but just `user`. Rails will match it correctly, so:

`get '/login' => 'user#login'`

P.S. Not sure if it is the only problem you are having

Comment: well it did fix something but i got a new error now Missing template user/login, application/login with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/kristjan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/kristjan/myApp/app/views" * "/home/kristjan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views" * "/home/kristjan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views"

Comment: so my fix was the fix for your problem. Now the problem is in views folder, you are missing user folder with login html file, and Rails do not know how to build output for this action. Assuming you are expecting html just add this file and everything should work

Comment: well i have a user folder in the views folder as user.html.erb and its compleatly clean i added a common h1 tag with some text but it didnt fix the problem. im pretty new with rails i didnt find any help on google so this place is my only way out atm :)

Comment: you should have following structure `app/views/user/login.html.erb`

Comment: yes that was my mistake thanks for the help :) got some more experience for ruby thnx to you:)

Comment: please mark my answer as solution if it is not a problem for you. ;) good luck.